# A simple way to change text field in an offline html page based on an input parameter in url

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple offline html page looking like this:

```
HEADER

Body Text
```

But the contents of the header and body text need to changed based on input param in url (I think it should be looking like this: "index.html?lang=abc"?), the text strings for on each lang are pre-defined and if possible both the javaScript code and the possible values of text fields should be stored inside the html page itself.

I have basically zero knowledge about html and JavaScript.

I tried to follow some examples and adapted some code samples on SO and google, and at least got the split lang parameter right, but while trying to change the text field it bricked my html and it can't be displayed. I cannot access Youtube during work hour to search for solutions there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can use JavaScript to parse the URL parameters and update the text content of your HTML elements accordingly. Try it out!

```js
    // Function to parse URL parameters
    function getUrlParameter(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
        var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
        var results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    };

    // Function to update text based on language parameter
    function updateText() {
        var lang = getUrlParameter('lang');
        var headerText, bodyText;

        // Define text for different languages
        switch (lang) {
            case 'en':
                headerText = 'English Header';
                bodyText = 'English Body Text';
                document.body.setAttribute('data-lang', 'en'); // declare font family for english  
                break;
            case 'fr':
                headerText = 'French Header';
                bodyText = 'French Body Text';
                document.body.setAttribute('data-lang', 'fr'); // Set language attribute for CSS styling
                break;
            default:
                headerText = 'Default Header';
                bodyText = 'Default Body Text';
        }

        // Update HTML elements with new text
        document.getElementById('header').innerText = headerText;
        document.getElementById('bodyText').innerText = bodyText;
    }

    // Call updateText function when the page loads
    window.onload = updateText;
```

```html
<style>
    /* Define font styles for different languages */
    h1 {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Default font */
    }
    p {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Default font */
    }
    /* You can do like this as much as you want */
    body[data-lang="fr"] h1 {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Font for French */
    }
    body[data-lang="fr"] p {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Font for French */
    }
</style>
<body data-lang="en">
    <h1 id="header">Header</h1>
    <p id="bodyText">Body Text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, very easy to understand, especially with someone who is familiar with C like me. Didn't know that you can change texts just by assigning an Id to it.

Comment: Another request from my boss is to change the text font based on the input lang "because this language looks better in this font". Could you help me with that, too?

Comment: I have added some styling and JavaScript code so you can set a font family for specific language .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what you want to do, so my example will be very basic.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>url</title>
</head>
  <body onload="parsePageUrl();">

    <h1>Page URL:</h1>

      <div id="divUrl">
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="divUrlSearch">
      </div>

    <script>
      function parsePageUrl() {
        const url = new URL(window.location.href);
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("divUrl");
        var objDivS = document.getElementById("divUrlSearch");
        objDiv.innerHTML = url.href;
        objDivS.innerHTML = url.search;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This example uses **body onload** to trigger the JavaScript function **parsePageUrl** which reads **window.location.href** into a new **URL**. Then the entire URL is written into the **div** object with the **id** that equals **divUrl**, and only the **search** part of the URL into another **div** object.

Comment: Hi, my request is basically very simple html site, no decoration, just a short header/title and a longer body text with changable contents based on the input parameters lang.
For example, if the url is "index.html?lang=en", the website is gonna be displayed as
"HEADER_IN_ENGLISH
Bodytext_in_english"

Answer (score 0):

Does your desire is to make a translation based on the lang param in URL?

I assume that your text element has a id = 'text'

`<p id="text">hello</p>`

```js
const queryString = window.location.search; // ?lang=vi
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); 
const lang = urlParams.get('lang'); // get the lang in URL

const textElement = document.querySelector('#text'); // assume that your text has a id="text"

textElement.innerText = "xin chao"; // update the content of the p tag with new text
```